# How to handle time out or idle time of user in application in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell How to handle time out or idle time of user in application in sencha touch.Suppose if user is not using the application more than 10 mins need to navigate login page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This plugin i am using in current app. https://github.com/arthurakay/ExtJS-Activity-Monitor check this

In launch function u can use this code, even u can set the time interval for check. please go through the Activity monitor js file u will get some idea. u have to do some customisation

```
Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.init({ verbose : true });
Ext.ux.ActivityMonitor.start();
```

Comment: Can u tell how to access this file from my app,Where i need to place ExtJS-Activity-Monitor.js